# Polynomial time reduction from NP Complete to other problems

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

Can any one clear my doubt please?

suppose I have a problem A which is known to be in NP-complete. and I have a another problem B for which we don't know the complexity class.

if I reduce A to B in polynomial time . we can say B also is in NP-Complete.

but..
if I reduce B to A in polynomial time . why can't I say B also in NP-Complete?

Answer (score 3):

> if I reduce A to B in polynomial time . we can say B also is in NP-Complete.

No, we can say that B is NP-hard. Completeness requires membership in NP as well, which does not follow from the assumptions.

For example, we can reduce 3SAT to the Halting Problem. The Halting Problem is not in NP (it's not even decidable).

> if I reduce B to A in polynomial time . why can't I say B also in NP-Complete?

We can say that B is in NP. One algorithm for B is to use the reduction and then solve A. B might be an easy problem like "length of the input is odd".

Comment: thank you sir, can you tell me the reason why we can't say B not in NP-complete..do we have any example?

Answer (score 0):

If A is NP-complete, you can reduce any problem in NP to A. The NP-complete problems are the hardest problems in NP.

If you can reduce A to B in polynomial time, it means that B is "at least as hard as" A, because if you can solve B, then becomes easy to solve A. So, if A is NP-complete and those are (by definition) the hardest problems in NP, B is also NP-complete (assuming B is in NP, otherwise it's just NP-hard).

On the other hand, being able to reduce B to A is like being able to kill an ant with a bazooka. You obviously can do it, but it doesn't mean that killing an ant is "bazooka-complete".